# Boolean operators precedence

Tags: boolean, operator-keyword, operator-precedence

I would like to know if operator precedence in programming languages depends on implementation or there is a fixed rule that all languages follow. And if possible, could you order the following operators with highest precedence first: AND, OR, NOT, XOR.

Comment: I can never remember the precedence of XOR but all the languages I've used have the same precedence for the other three.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I googled and found out [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Programming_languages) which says that some languages like APL and SmallTalk do not have operator precedence rules and they strictly evaluate expressions from left to right/left to right.

However,relative order of precedence followed is NOT > XOR > AND > OR in most of the languages especially those derived from C

Comment: According to [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), C's precedence is actualy NOT > AND > XOR > OR, with AND coming before XOR. JavaScript and Java also follow this order.

Comment: @mbomb007 It's the **Bitwise AND** not the **Logical AND**

Comment: @AndrewNaguib Read the link I posted. Bitwise AND comes before Bitwise XOR in C.

Comment: Yes, he doesn’t mean the bitwise AND, he is mentioning the logical AND.

Comment: C/C++ doesn't have a logical XOR, only a bitwise XOR. An actually no language that I know of has a logical XOR. XOR makes a lot of sense when doing bitwise operations, but with boolean operations you can resolve it using combinations of AND and OR, or other higher level language constructs.

Comment: @Petruza C# allow `^` to reuse on boolean operator because it has specific boolean type. And it make somehow a compact logic albeit unfamiliar for the eye

Comment: And if you don't feel right using `^` as a logical XOR you can use `!=` which will evaluate the same as XOR.

Comment: Java also has the ^ XOR

Answer (score 18):

You have seen that when expressions mix && with || that evaluation must be done in the correct order. Parentheses can be used to group operands with their correct operator, just like in arithmetic. Also like arithmetic operators, logical operators have precedence that determines how things are grouped in the absence of parentheses.

In an expression, the operator with the highest precedence is grouped with its operand(s) first, then the next highest operator will be grouped with its operands, and so on. If there are several logical operators of the same precedence, they will be examined left to right.

It is common for programmers to use parentheses to group operands together for readability even when operator precedence alone would work.

[image]

[Source](https://chortle.ccsu.edu/java5/Notes/chap40/ch40_16.html)

Comment: The first 3 asserts here are totally redundant and prove nothing.
If the precedence of the `&&` and `||` were opposite, the expressions on the left side of `==` still evaluate to the exact same values

Answer (score 4):

Boolean or bitwise? There is no fixed rule, most languages have similar rules but differ in details. Look it up in the language definition.

Comment: Alright. I had boolean operators in mind when posting. Thanks for reminding me of bitwise operators.

Answer (score 4):

There are three basic Boolean operators: NOT, AND, OR. XOR is just a simple version of `A AND NOT B OR NOT A AND B` or `(A OR NOT B) AND (NOT A OR B)`. So, only these three have common precedence: NOT > AND > OR. XOR has different position in languages, but it has surely not higher precedence than AND and not lower than OR. Most languages (e.g. C/C++/Javascript etc.) have it between AND and OR, but in other ones (e.g. Perl) XOR has the same precedence as OR.

(OR can be expressed using only AND and NOT, but it is still a basic operator: `A OR B = NOT(NOT A AND NOT B)`)

Comment: Is there a good reason to have different precedence? I think that (in an ideal world) boolean operators should have the same level of precedence and logical operations to be always performed from left to right. Is there a good reason to be in another way? `true xor false or true` should be evaluated as true (`(true xor false) or true`), not as false  (`true xor (false or true)`)

Comment: Yes. The reason is very similar to arithmetic operators. This is a "different algebra" (boolean algebra). AND is a kind of multiplication, and OR is  like addition. There are areas, where it is more important than standard algebra (e.g. construction of digital circuits).

Comment: You can also abbreviate boolean XOR as `A != B`. But then you get into the precedence ordering of comparison operators vs. boolean operators. So be careful.

Answer (score 1):

Obvious and easy way to prove that AND is of higher precedence than OR is to compare results of statements with and without parentheses:

```
std::cout << std::boolalpha;
std::cout << ( true || false && false )     << std::endl;   // gives true
std::cout << ( ( true || false ) && false ) << std::endl;   // gives false
```

Answer (score 1):

In traditional Boolean algebra, the precedence is *not* > *and* > *or*, if you write the *not* as an overbar. *and* is "multiplicative", *or* is "additive". The case of *not* as an operator is less clear. IMO, `xor` should be assigned the same priority as the inclusive `or`.

- In C/C++, `!` > `!=` > `&&` > `||` (there is no logical `^`, `!=` acts as a *xor*)
- In C#, `!` > `&` > `^` > `|`
- In Visual Basic, `Not` > `And` > `Or` > `Xor`
- In FORTRAN, `.not.` > `/=` > `.and.` > `.or.` (there is no `.xor.`, `/=` acts as a *xor*)
- In Python, `!=` > `not` > `and` > `or` (there is no `xor`, `!=` acts as *xor*)
- In Pascal, `not` > `and` > `or` > `<>` (there is no `xor`, `<>` acts as *xor*)