# Select only rows where date in one column falls between two dates in other columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server from DBeaver on Linux. When I put this line in the `SELECT` statement, it works perfectly and creates a new column where the Y's and N's are correct.

```
CASE 
    WHEN t.event_date BETWEEN p.BaseStart AND p.BaseEnd 
        THEN 'Y' 
        ELSE 'N' 
END AS varnew
```

However what I really want to do is simply retain only rows where `t.event_date` is between `p.BaseStart` and `p.BaseEnd` (all in separate columns). It might have something to do with the data format because each of the dates is shown in YYYY-MM-DD format.

I have also tried

```
WHERE 
 .... several conditions ...
AND 
    t.event_date BETWEEN p.BaseStart AND p.BaseEnd
```

but it does not select at all, just brings all rows that meet the other conditions in the WHERE statement. I've tried using CAST, CONVERT and others to get the dates into the correct format but that doesn't work either.  So I have a couple of questions:

1. How is it possible that the same code works in SELECT but does not in WHERE statements?
2. Is it possible to do the selection in the SELECT statement and retain only those that match the condition, I don't need any new variables?
3. Is there an easy way to fix the problem in the WHERE statement such that it recognises the dates correctly?  Thx. J.

This is my code, names changed a little

```
SELECT 
    t.id,
    COUNT(t.code) OVER(PARTITION BY t.id) AS NUMTRTS, 
    t.anotherid,
    p.BaseStart,
    p.BaseEnd,
    t.code AS 'MC',
    t.date AS 'MD'
    --CASE WHEN t.date BETWEEN p.BaseStart AND p.BaseEnd THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS varnew
FROM
    ther t
JOIN 
    prac p ON t.id = p.id
WHERE
    t.code LIKE 'c1[1234]__'
    OR 
    t.code LIKE 'c2[abc]__'
    OR 
    t.code LIKE 'c3[179]__'
    OR 
    t.code LIKE 'c4[13]__'
    OR 
    t.code LIKE 'c5[56]__'
    OR 
    t.code LIKE 'c[67A]___'
    OR 
    t.code LIKE 'ck1__'
    AND 
    t.code NOT IN ('c1D9.')
    AND 
    t.code NOT LIKE 'c51[MN].'
    AND 
    t.event_date BETWEEN p.BaseStart AND p.BaseEnd
ORDER BY
    t.id, MedDate
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect results?

Comment: Lemme guess, the complete WHERE clause also contains some `OR` and without using parenthesis `()`

Comment: It's tough to answer without knowing what your JOIN clause, and indeed your whole query, looks like. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: @LukStorms It does contain 6 OR statements and this one is the last of 3 AND statements, apologies for naitivity, would parentheses fix the problem?

Comment: You need to ask with a [mre]   (and not with HALF sql statements, which leaves room for a lot a guessing)

Comment: You have OR there. Use parentheses.

Comment: Side point: `BETWEEN` on datetime values is usually a bad idea, because it is inclusive on both end. You should probably have an exclusive end time such as `(t.event_date >= p.BaseStart AND t.event_date < p.BaseEnd)`

Comment: It's just that the  `AND` are evaluated before the `OR`. Not only in SQL. So `x OR y AND z` is actually `x OR (y AND z)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need parenthesis to correctly apply your logic, such as:

```
where (
     t.code LIKE 'c1[1234]__'
  OR t.code LIKE 'c2[abc]__'
  OR t.code LIKE 'c3[179]__'
  OR t.code LIKE 'c4[13]__'
  OR t.code LIKE 'c5[56]__'
  OR t.code LIKE 'c[67A]___'
  OR t.code LIKE 'ck1__'
)
AND t.code NOT IN ('c1D9.')
AND t.code NOT LIKE 'c51[MN].'
AND t.event_date BETWEEN p.BaseStart AND p.BaseEnd
```

Comment: Yup ... that fixed it. I am embarrassed but have read lots around this and never been recommended to enclose 'OR' statements in parenthesis.  Leaves me asking, why for 'OR' and not 'AND' .....?  Also is this an idiosyncrasy of sql-server only, or true of most flavours of sql?  Thx. J.

Comment: This is not and idiosyncrasy of anything, it's [boolean algebra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12494568/boolean-operators-precedence)

Comment: Is this what you mean? "Boolean or bitwise? There is no fixed rule, most languages have similar rules but differ in details. Look it up in the language definition."